# Prove the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix with 2 along the diagonal and -1 below and above

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$T_N = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -1&    &0\\\ -1 & 2&...&\\\  &...&...&-1 \\\ 0&   &-1&2 \end{pmatrix}_{N \times N}$$
Prove that the eigenvalues of $T_N$ are $\lambda_j = 2(1-\cos(\frac{\pi j}{N+1}))$ and the corresponding
eigenvectors are $z_j$ , where the k−th component of $z_j$ is
$$z_j(k) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{N+1}}\sin (\frac{jk\pi}{N+1})$$

Hi, can anyone help? I have no idea, Thanks!

Comment: They are giving you the eigenvalues and the eigenvectors, you just need to check that they are so.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: Try computing how does the matrix act on a vector with $k$-th component given by $\exp(ik\pi/N)$ or $\exp(-ik\pi/N)$. Playing with this ansatz, maybe shifting $N \mapsto N+1$ should lead to the right result. (The idea comes from interpreting the matrix as discretized derivative.)